# How to solve this adb grant permission error on Android?

Tags: android, adb

want to grant android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION to my apk file.

adb command i used:

```
pm grant com.maxmpz.equalizer android.permission.DUMP
```

**But it always show this error:**

```
PS C:\Users\Marhaba\Desktop\Desktop\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> ./adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached

PS C:\Users\Marhaba\Desktop\Desktop\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools>
PS C:\Users\Marhaba\Desktop\Desktop\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> ./adb devices
List of devices attached
69WSMZFEF6WG4DYT        device

PS C:\Users\Marhaba\Desktop\Desktop\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> ./adb shell pm grant com.maxmpz.equalizer android.permission.DUMP
Security exception: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.

java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1955)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1983)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:2235)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.access$900(PermissionManagerService.java:133)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService$PermissionManagerServiceInternalImpl.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:3332)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PackageManagerService.java:6671)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2030)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:238)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:24187)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5400)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4819)
        at com.android.server.pm.OppoPackageManagerService.onTransact(OppoPackageManagerService.java:83)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
PS C:\Users\Marhaba\Desktop\Desktop\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> ./adb shell pm grant com.maxmpz.equalizer android.permission.DUMP
Security exception: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.

java.lang.SecurityException: grantRuntimePermission: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1955)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1983)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:2235)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.access$900(PermissionManagerService.java:133)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService$PermissionManagerServiceInternalImpl.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:3332)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PackageManagerService.java:6671)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2030)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:238)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:24187)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5400)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4819)
        at com.android.server.pm.OppoPackageManagerService.onTransact(OppoPackageManagerService.java:83)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
PS C:\Users\Marhaba\Desktop\Desktop\platform-tools_r30.0.5-windows\platform-tools> ok
```

Answer (score 0):

android.permission.DUMP can be granted to system app only (Not for use by third-party applications) : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#DUMP

Answer (score 0):

pm grant com.maxmpz.equalizer android.permission.DUMP